# Adding (even empty) argument to macro changes subfigure alignment with subcaption package

Tags: macros, vertical-alignment, subcaption

I have two subfigures in a figure. The content of one of them is given by a macro I've defined. The other subfigure's content is exactly the defined output of the macro. This results in the subfigures being misaligned. It seems to only happen when the macro takes arguments, even if those arguments are never used. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\mymacro}{
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
}

\newcommand{\myothermacro}[1]{
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\mymacro
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{No arguments}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\myothermacro{}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{One argument}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case you're wondering why I don't just use the macro twice, in my actual application I want to reproduce the macro with one small change for one subfigure, and this led me to the MWE above. I did not observe this same behavior with the package subfig. Does anyone know why this happens and if there's an easy fix?

Comment: `\myothermacro` adds 1 space then  #1 then  1 space and you have `\myothermacro{} ` which has another space after it so you are adding three spaces place `%` at ends of lines if you do not intend to add space characters

Answer (score 1):

As @David Carlisle points out, in general `LaTeX` makes a space from each newline. So to put his comment into a solution, you'd have to change your macros to read:

```
\newcommand{\mymacro}{%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
}

\newcommand{\myothermacro}[1]{%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
}
```

---

Alternatively for a really short macro, you can also write it into a single line of code, but this reduces readability quite easy:

```
\newcommand{\mymacro}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}}

\newcommand{\myothermacro}[1]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
```